# Modern GPU internals

Tags: graphics-card

does anyone know if there are some good detailed resources around on GPU internals, especially, communication between GPU and CPU, i.e. how does GPU acquire its share of work, what kind of instructions does it perform, and to what extent it computes 3d scenes.

I'm certainly not looking for Wiki style article with no details at all.

Thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this](http://www.x.org/docs/AMD/), [this](http://www.x.org/docs/intel/) and [this](http://www.x.org/docs/via/) good enough for you? :)